# Caching of static assets when index.html gets 304 on second request?

Tags: google-chrome, http, nginx

I am noticing this behavior and I'm not sure how this works. I have an Nginx Server which doesn't send any caching headers. It only sends E-Tags and Last Modified header. So the second time when I visit the site, the browser sends a request and receives 304 response code from Nginx. After that all static assets from the site are automatically served from the browser cache. I'm not sure why this happens.
My understanding was for Caching to happen, the server needs to send either Cache-Control headers expires headers with the response, but here without these, the files are still cached.
Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: This could be happen if your browser send a `If-Not-Modified-Since` header among the other request headres. If you want to completely disable any caching try `add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";`. Or if you need this for debugging only, just open DevTools and check "Disable cache" on the "Network" tab.

Comment: Thanks @IvanShatsky.
What I'm observing is my page consists of index.html and index.js.

Now when index.html gets 304 response, the browser is not sending fresh request for index.js, but is simply showing 200 status and serving from cache. 
I simply do not understand why this is happening. If I set Cache headers from Nginx, then browser starts making fresh request.

Comment: Is there any understanding of how this works? I am seeing the same behavior if chrome (not checked with other browsers) gets a 304 response for the document request, It would not send requests for any of the javascript/css files. It would just use them from memory/disk but when it gets 200 it is making a new request to fetch all those.